# リサイズした際、指定クラス名の(画面上の)横幅サイズを取得したい

Tags: javascript, css, dom

**前提**
・レスポンシブサイト

```
<div class="hoge">
```

・hogeクラスは複数存在するが、全て同じサイズの動き(画面幅に応じた適切な幅で表示)

---

**知りたいこと**
・リサイズする度ごとに、画面上の「div hogeクラス」サイズを取得したい
※Chromeコンソール画面で、指定div要素にマウスオーバーした際に表示されるサイズ(オリジナルではなく画面上の表示サイズ)を取得したい

---

**最終的にやりたいこと**
・「div hogeクラス」の画面上の横幅を基準として、このdiv内で読み込む画像パスを条件分岐したい

Comment: [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQueryを使用しない場合、以下のコードでwidthを取得できます。

```html
<div class="hoge">hoge</div>
<script>
(function(){
  var onResize= function(){
    var element= document.querySelector('.hoge');
    var boundingClientRect= element.getBoundingClientRect();

    if(boundingClientRect.width>500){
      console.log('over 500',boundingClientRect.width);
    }
    else{
      console.log('500 or less',boundingClientRect.width);
    }
  }

  addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',onResize);
  addEventListener('resize',onResize);
})();
</script>
```

以下の点に注意してください。

- marin, padding, [box-sizing](http://kouto-swiss.io/docs.html#box-sizing-reset)などのスタイルを定義している要素の場合、意図したwidthを取得出来ない場合があります。[window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)の使用を検討してください。
- 対象の要素が動的に追加／削除／変更される場合、jQueryの[$(document).on()](http://qiita.com/sasaplus1/items/0ec036c1a8789b9d9907#2-3)などで、DOMの変更を監視する必要があります。

Answer (score 0):

jQueryを使用しているという前提でよければ・・・

```
$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
    console.debug($('.hoge').first().outerWidth());
});
```